# How to prevent saving invalid ids in associative table in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, many-to-many

I have two tables in my Rails app: `Category` and `Service`. I have also created an associative table `CategoriesService` between them and everything works right except validation of ids on the `CategoriesService` table - I just noticed I am able to create an association with a non-existent record. I wonder how could I fix it properly - I suspect that Rails should let us create some database-level validation of that, which could be faster and cleaner. I defined my models that way:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :services
end

class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class CategoriesService < ApplicationRecord
end
```

I was thinking that creating `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship would ensure this kind of validation itself, but I can see I was wrong. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#activerecord):

> *Prefer `has_many :through` to `has_and_belongs_to_many`. Using `has_many :through` allows additional attributes and validations on the join model.*

In your case:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories_services
  has_many :services, through: :categories_services
end

class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categories_services
  has_many :categories, through: :categories_services
end

class CategoriesService < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :service

  # if not using Rails 5:
  validates :category, presence: true
  validates :service, presence: true
  # if using Rails 5, a `belongs_to` will auto-validate the presence
end
```

Using the join model (and not the `has_and_belongs_to_many`), you have a better control of the many-to-many relation:

- you (can) have the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields on the join table, automatically managed by Rails as usual
- you could improve your join model to have, for example, a column `position` and then you could offer a feature of sorting the `services` of a specific `category`, a `favorite` boolean column, etc.

---

Additionally, you can (and I recommend you to do so) enforce this validation by adding some constraints in your Database:

```
# PostgreSQL
CREATE TABLE categories_services (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  category_id integer REFERENCES categories NOT NULL,
  service_id integer REFERENCES services NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
```